# What are the technology and design parameters that mostly affect yield?

Tags: manufacturing

I understand that when an integrated circuit is manufactured we speak of yield as the ratio of 'good' devices over manufactured devices.

Since 'good' is quite ambiguous I am going to limit the question a bit.

First of all we are not speaking of what happens to a singulated device when it leaves the FAB. Packaging, trimming, soldering should not be taken in account here. A 'good' device is something that a manufacturer would put in a package, possibly in an ATE machine, to try and sell it.

A device can be born dead for a number of reasons, which might be mitigated both through careful design and careful manufacturing in FAB. There finally are some parameters that usually are not in control of the designer or the manufacturer.

To give a couple of examples:

- Redundancy in the design can mitigate the effects of a dead gate
- Keeping the machines clean avoids particles that would contaminate the silicon
- Chip area though is usually something that can be changed not much

My question then is:

What are the technology and design parameter that mostly affect yield? Is it just about die size? Does the feature size has anything to do with that? Is it better to make a smaller chip with smaller features (if possible), or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

The total die size has a big impact in yield.  Bigger dies mean less total dies from a single wafer, which means you might have 1 bad die out of 50 dies for a big die, instead of 1 bad die out of 100 dies for a smaller die.  An imperfection on a big die will kill that whole wafer area, where you could have fit 5 or 10 smaller dies, and only 1 die dies as a result of imperfections.

The edges of a wafer are typically where the most imperfections occur.  With smaller dies, you get more dies away from the edge of the wafer.  Bigger dies result in more dies sitting closer to the edge than that sweet, juicy silicon in the center.

Feature size also plays a role in yield, especially when first rolling out a new feature size.  AMD and nVidia both got hurt by TSMC when they went to TSMC's 40nm process back in 2010 for the Radeon 5000 and GF100s, respectively.  [Initial yields were down in the 40% range](http://www.techspot.com/news/36781-tsmc-40nm-yield-issues-to-affect-amd-and-nvidia.html).  But here in 2016, nVidia is using TSCM's 28nm process with good results.  My google-fu hasn't been able to get hard numbers on the yield.

Small feature means advances in lithography, and that means problems, as with everything on the bleeding edge.  Using TSMC's 40nm process in 2016 should give high yields because it's now a mature process.

In short, if you're looking for absolutely highest yields, small dies with big feature sizes will give the biggest yields.

Answer (score 1):

I used to categorized yields in Mfg in Root Cause Analysis under 3 categories.

- bad design
- bad process
- bad material
- These all depend on the **difficulty, maturity and direct control** of each.

  - that is items within inside one's immediate capability, like switch supplier, change customer design, modify process parameters
  - then dozens of sub-categories under each category

    - The defect ratio is highly dependent on skill, experience and quality of the 3 main categories for any given technology from mature to bleeding-edge.
    - It also depends on the quality of the design for test (DFT) for early % fault detection, Fault isolation and good management support to ensure DFT is done up front with the original product design, and not an afterthought. Another major factor for Design Quality factor is DVT & PVT prove-in.

It may be possible to give isolated examples on each of the 3 major categories.

**It cannot be stressed enough that cleanliness** ( is godliness) and contamination impurities in the process is a major process control in capacitors, solder and IC fabrication.  Not just a cursory sweep in a class 100 clean room, but an analytical method of determining mass spectrographic results of contaminants and target of class 1 clean room, which is nearly impossible at the foot level, without flow control from air flow from people moving in clean sticky booties over shoes and continous monitoring with a 16 channel laser particle counter, air de-ionizers etc.